# Tesseract OCR with Kivy App

Tags: kivy, tesseract, python-tesseract, tess-two

Is it possible to integrate Tesseract-OCR (or Tess-Two) with a Kivy app?
I'm looking to create an Android app for OCR-based text recognition using the Kivy Framework.
I've worked with the Tesseract API on my PC for sometime and am wondering if there is a way to make use of it's functionality for a Kivy app.
If no, are there any alternatives?

Comment: Hi, did you ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible to build tesseract-ocr for Android (you can look it up, maybe people have done so). If so, you can probably use it with Kivy in the normal way, but would need to write a [recipe](http://python-for-android.readthedocs.io/en/latest/recipes/) for it. It looks like this could be relatively complex, since it's a big C++ library, but it's hard to say for sure.