# How to use Pytesseract for a Kivy app on Android?

Tags: python, kivy, tesseract, python-tesseract

So I am planning to use Tesseract for a Kivy app. But I am not sure if it will work on Android, because in Tesseract you have to give a path to the executable. I have read a post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45909130/tesseract-ocr-with-kivy-app)  about this, and it was said that we need a recipe or wrapper for it. And luckily someone made a wrapper for it [here](https://github.com/madmaze/pytesseract). It is named pytesseract, but I am still not sure if I can use it. Because I still have to give it a path where my tesseract.exe is located.

```
import pytesseract
tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract'
print(pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('test.png')))
```

So my final question is, how could I make a build with buildozer when I have this kind of exe file. Should I do some specific changes in buildozer.spec file.